# Pass value on the one form to get that value in other form in cakephp using jquery and attr href

Tags: jquery, cakephp, filter, href

```
"Hello Friends, i am newb in web development. bear with my silly question. i checed my requirement but i dint get similar match.
```

**Query -** 
    i am working on CRM and i have one form where i am selecting value from dialog     box      from Account table. There are Contacts under Account . when i am selecting   Account i could get the id of the selected account but i dont know how to filter that id with contacts (i have foreign key in contact table id matching in contact). When i click on select contact button dialog box should show only filtered contact which comes under selected account."
using this code i get value of selected Account

```
$('#contact-popup').bind("click", function(){
    var val = $('#OpportunityAccleadId').val();
    $.colorbox({ href:$(this).attr('href')+'/'+val });
    return false;
});
```

GET localhost/cakeproject/crm1/opportunities/contact_search/6
i got this link, i checked in fire bug . 
Now how i can use this id 6 to contact_search.ctp file to filter the contact . Can it possible or do i need to work on controller logic.

Account we are selecting at the time of adding data thats why i chosen JS to build.

any help will be helpful for me. Thankx in advance.

Comment: I think you are talking about `autocomplete`. You can use Jquery UI. And  there are also so many Jquery plugins available on autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankx Fazal for your reply. actually i have one add page and on the same page first i select account. and then contact from dialog box. i wanted the contacts from selected account only.

i got solution on this. i have made changes on below code .

previous code

```
$('#contact-popup').bind("click", function(){
    var val = $('#OpportunityAccleadId').val();
    $.colorbox({ href:$(this).attr('href')+'/'+val });
    return false;
});
```

current code - 
    $('#contact-popup').bind("click", function(){
        var val = $('#OpportunityAccleadId').val();
        $.colorbox({ href:$(this).attr('href')+'/q='+val });
        return false;
    });

i got hidden ID with the help of this code from add page. then i add condition in contactsearch dialog box page.

i took value of that id in $_GET['q'] and matched with account id.

```
if($variable['model']['id'] == $_GET['q']){
    //add code to display
}
```

Thankx fazal.